# How to use WebRequest to post data and get response from a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to implement an application to post request to a given url and get response.

What are the best methods to post request to a given url and get response?

Please help.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

How about this?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestPostExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/PostAccepter.aspx ");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close ();

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

It's taken from MSDN: [MSDN on WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)