# How to get input from website to .NET console application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, input, csc

Is there anyway to obtain values from asp.net website and send it .net console application. Program hits to Console.ReadLine() and I need it to collect input from asp.net website one way or another.

Comment: Everything explined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502500/how-to-use-webrequest-to-post-data-and-get-response-from-a-webpage

Comment: What is this "input"?  Are you looking to scrape some data from a webpage?  If that's the case it doesn't matter what server-side technology is used to build the webpage, all you need to do is make a request for the page and parse the data from the response.  "Screen scraping" or "website scraping" are good terms to search for countless examples on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string from a webpage by using

```
var a = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(myUrl);
```

And if you want it as output to console you can

```
System.Console.WriteLine(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(myUrl));
```