# How to download string this site c#

Tags: c#, webclient

i have xml data, and i need download to string this. But c# return error like this "Remote adress return error" , but this site is alive and work on my firefox. How to download this data?

My codes:

```
 WebClient x = new WebClient();
       string y= x.DownloadString("http://dizilab.com/diziler.xml");
       MessageBox.Show(y);
```

Comment: When do you get the error? On your second line of code where you actually call `x.DownloadString()`?

Comment: The first time I tried to load the file it sent me to a cloudFlare countdown page. What is the exact error?

Comment: yes this problem is cloudflare, how to access xml data without cloudflare

Comment: CloudFlare has a timer feature enabled that prevents this site from various attacks... There is no way of getting around this

Comment: This can help you.

[How to use WebRequest to post data and get response from a webpage][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502500/how-to-use-webrequest-to-post-data-and-get-response-from-a-webpage

Comment: @Lali thanks for answer but its not work :(

Answer (score 0):

According to a CloudFlare employee who answered this question: [cURL - Load a site with CloudFlare protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500088/curl-load-a-site-with-cloudflare-protection)

If you own the hosted site, you can whitelist your calling domain to allow access, otherwise you "supposedly" have no way of getting around this protection. However, there is a second answer that offers an option that you may find useful if you're familiar with cURL.

Comment: No I think you just have to use a user-agent for something like mozilla or ie or some browser, I'm not sure myself but it has worked for other people