# How to add direction of the route on the google map?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I have two connected points on the map and I want to know which one is startpoint and endpoint so I want to add direction(arrows) of the route. How can I do it using c#?
This is my code:

```
PointLatLng start1 = new PointLatLng(42.252938, 42.680411);
PointLatLng end1 = new PointLatLng(42.256321, 42.675658);
GDirections dir1;
var path1 = GMapProviders.GoogleMap.GetDirections(out dir1, start1, end1, false, false, true, true, true);
GMapRoute route1 = new GMapRoute(dir1.Route, "path1");
route1.Stroke.Color = Color.Red;
GMapOverlay lay1 = new GMapOverlay("route1");
lay1.Routes.Add(route1);
map.Overlays.Add(lay1);
```

Comment: Would be ok with a javascript solution for this?

Comment: Adding direction arrows on the route, you can as well use javascript since google has provided very good javascript resource to its map api.

Comment: Cann't I do it using c#?

Comment: With C#, after making API calls, you will have to work your way out. Refer to- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597229/google-maps-api-for-c-sharp. As for javascript there is lot of code and resources provided for google javascript api

Comment: I will show. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send a `web request` to google maps api.

In order to do this, you may follow these steps :

Create a web request in C# and pass start and endpoint as parameters , have a look at code snippet below (also [refer docs here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsRequests))

Pay special attention to this part (This is what you need to use) :

> If you pass coordinates, they are used unchanged to calculate
>   directions. Ensure that no space exists between the latitude and
>   longitude values. origin=41.43206,-81.38992

```
string gMapsUrl = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=42.252938,42.680411&destination=42.256321,42.675658&key=YOUR_API_KEY";

WebRequest directionReq = WebRequest.Create(gMapsUrl);

WebResponse directionResponse = directionReq.GetResponse();

Stream data = directionResponse.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

// get json-formatted string from maps api
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

response.Close();
```

Notice how i used this :

```
origin=42.252938,42.680411&destination=42.256321,42.675658
```

in request URL.

Also refer this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597229/google-maps-api-for-c-sharp) for sample response
Also use `using System.Net;` in your class for using `WebRequest`

Follow this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502529/1531476) for constructing `webRequests`

Comment: I started coding on c# about one week ago so I don't know it very well. I have red line under WebRequest and WebResponse, do I need to add some classes? "using System.NET" or something like that?

Comment: please see updated answer, kindly upvote and accept as answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes I figured out how it works. I also have one question please: can I draw direction on the google map? Here is shown what I want https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMYB7.jpg